# Using COM Exe Server w/o Registry in Win7

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, com

I have an existing COM Exe Server,  and VBA or .NET code calling it. We'd like to make it work w/o needing to install or modify the registry so that other users that are not admins on their machines can use it.

Let's assume changing/modifying the COM Exe Server is not possible (expensive).

**Question 1:** 
From what I undertand in [Registering a Running EXE Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the EXE server can call CoRegisterClassObject to register the CLSID in the class table.   Does that mean clients should be able to CoGetClassObject from there? (even w/o registry entries for that type/class?)

**Question 2:** 
If the above is correct, my EXE Server uses CComModule (deprecated, yes) and I can see is is indeed calling CoRegisterClassObject.  Is there a way to verify the class table so see that is is done correctly?

**Question 3:**
This is the snippet I am using. clsid and iid refer to the coresponding clsid and iid guids. It fails with *Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155)* in the call to CreateInstance. This makes me sad, any idea on what might be wrong?

```
            var factory = UnsafeNativeMethods.CoGetClassObject(
            clsid,
            RegistrationClassContext.LocalServer,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            typeof(UnsafeNativeMethods.IClassFactory).GUID)
                      as UnsafeNativeMethods.IClassFactory;

            factory.CreateInstance(null, ref iid, out obj);
```

Comment: How would you register your class without an administrator rights? Once you're component has registered, non-admin users should be able to execute code calling COM functionality, I think.

Comment: Correct. What I'm trying to do is Registry-Free Activation (you can do this with DLL Servers).  Let's say there's a lot of users and changes happen a lot, so requiring registration is not that nice. I modified the first paragraph to make this a bit clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Question 1: From what I undertand in Registering a Running EXE Server,
>   the EXE server can call CoRegisterClassObject to register the CLSID in
>   the class table. Does that mean clients should be able to
>   CoGetClassObject from there? (even w/o registry entries for that
>   type/class?)

Yes. `CoRegisterClassObject` will be enough (without registry) to make your out-of-proc object available to any client which calls `CoCreateInstance` with `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`. However, you may have problems with marshaling calls, because the COM proxy/stub DLL and/or type library are not registered. So, a well-know interfaces like `IDispatch`, `IOleCommandTarget` etc will be marshaled without problems, but any custom interfaces will fail.

There are other ways to make you EXE server available to the clients, though. To name a few: [`RegisterActiveObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`IRunningObjectTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Question 2: If the above is correct, my EXE Server uses CComModule
>   (deprecated, yes) and I can see is is indeed calling
>   CoRegisterClassObject. Is there a way to verify the class table so see
>   that is is done correctly?

I can only think of calling `CoGetClassObject` or `CoCreateInstance` (either needs `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` flag) to verify that.

> Question 3: This is the snippet I am using. clsid and iid refer to the
>   coresponding clsid and iid guids. It fails with Interface not
>   registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155) in the call to
>   CreateInstance. This makes me sad, any idea on what might be wrong?

That's weird. The COM standard marshaler returns 0x80040155 (REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG) if it can't find a proxy/stub factory for an interface, but `IClassFactory` doesn't require a custom proxy. Are you sure you have a correct `GUID` in your C# definition of `IClassFactory`? That should be `Guid("00000001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")`.

Comment: The GUID is correct. The CoGetClassObject call itself is fine. The exception happens in the factory.CreateInstance  call. I guess that's because of the custom interface issues you mention?  I will try the ROT way.

Comment: @moogs, hmm, `IClassFactory` is not a custom interface, and your're not creating an actual object, just retrieving a factory. What happens if you *do* register this EXE server?

Comment: that's right. retrieving the IClassFactory itself works fine.   But CreateInstance with the custom interface ("iid" refers to a custom one) fails.     The code works all fine on a machine with the EXE server registered.

Comment: @moogs, then that's it. I thought that'd be CoGetClassObject what resulted with the error. The ROT will **not** help either. If you want to avoid using registry, you'll have to give up on your custom interfaces, and use a standard one, like `IDispatch`.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds promising. The EXE Server fortunately implements IDispatch.  I am able to get an instance. However, when I either Type.Invoke() or IDispatch.GetIDsOfNames(), I get a 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED).     The code works fine on the machine where is it registered.

Comment: @moogs, ATL implements `IDispatch` using `ITypeInfo::Invoke`, and the type library has to be registered for that. You have two options: 1) implement it by manually; 2) override ATL's implementation and use `LoadTypeLib` to load the typelib from file.

Comment: i actually have it working now. The error earlier caused me to look further...and did LoadTypeLib/RegisterTypeLibForUser.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @moogs, no problem. If you do `RegisterTypeLibForUser`, you can use your custom dual (`IDispatch`-derived) interface directly. The OLE Automation marshaller will use the type library to marshal calls. Note however, this will still alter the registry of the user account (under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive).